# PHP using Code Igniter - Object Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter

> View : vw_home.php

```
<?php echo "hello world "; ?>
```

> Controller : home.php

```
 <?php
          defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
             class home extends CI_Controller{
                 function __construct(){
                    parent::__construct();
                  }
                 function index(){
                    $data['page_title']="WELCOME | CSB SDP";
                    $this->load->view('SideBar',$data);    
                }
           }
     }
```

> Route :

```
<?php
       defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
           $route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';
 ?>
```

_I guess the model is not applicable here;  I am a newbie in Codeigniter and it turns out to have an error

> OBJECT NOT FOUND .

can anyone please help me :( what else lack here ?

Comment: what the line of that code does the error point to ?

Comment: Please post full error log detail.

Comment: First letter of class and file name must be upper case only. In Ci3 versions. As explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first letter of file and class name capital your `home.php` should be `Home.php`

and

```
  class home extends CI_Controller{
```

should

```
  class Home extends CI_Controller{
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$route['default_controller']` from

`$route['default_controller']='home\index'`

to

`$route['default_controller']='home'`

because it is finding the controler `index` inside the `home` folder.

Comment: accept this as an answer if this will satisfy you as solution on your problem